# Is it possible to add view to the end of UIScrollView's content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've searched a bit, but couldn't find anything similar to my question, is it possible to add a view to the end of UIScrollView's content?

For example lets say that I have some kind of banner that I want to show only if the user reaches the end of the scroller, how can I add him at the end of the scroller content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the end of the scroll view using the contentSize.height (the contentsize is the size of the scrollable area).

If your view is for example, 50 pt height, you can set the origin of your view to:

```
float originYView = myScrollView.contentSize.height - 50;
```

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW1):

[image]

Check the UIScrollView Programming guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/

Comment: And when views are using autolayout it may be necessary to add some constraints programatically too.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewIWantToAdd.frame = cgrectmake(viewIWantToAdd.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.scrollView.conentSize.height,
                                  viewIWantToAdd.frame.size.width,
                                  viewIWantToAdd.frame.origin.height);

self.scrollView.contentSize = cgSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width,
                                         self.scrollView.contentSize.height + viewIWantToAdd.frame.size.height);

[self.scrollView addSubview:viewIWantToAdd];
```

There might be some syntax errors, I am on a pc and wrote it straight in the browser.  If you want to add some padding between the banner and the content, just do:

```
int padding = 20;

viewIWantToAdd.frame = cgrectmake(viewIWantToAdd.frame.origin.x,
                                      self.scrollView.conentSize.height + padding,
                                      viewIWantToAdd.frame.size.width,
                                      viewIWantToAdd.frame.origin.height);

self.scrollView.contentSize = cgSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width,
                                         self.scrollView.contentSize.height + viewIWantToAdd.frame.size.height + padding);

[self.scrollView addSubview:viewIWantToAdd];
```